# Set-Variable powershell. How do I link a variable to an exe file?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, variables

I'm quite new to the PowerShell environment, but I'm supposed to use it for "Learn python the hard way". In the mac terminal you can just type:

```
python script.py
```

In PowerShell on Windows this does not work. I'd like to be in any folder in my computer and execute python on a script in that folder. For that I believe the best thing to do is `create a variable that calls python.exe` instead of having to list the path every time.

I have tried declaring a python variable in the `Command Prompt` window but they don't seem to carry over.

Any small additional information like the name of the action I'm trying to do would be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty easy to do using the `Set-Alias` instead of `Set-Variable`. You will basically just pick up the path and how you want to reference it in your code.

I do this often for when [I need to call `7z.exe`](https://meltondba.wordpress.com/stackexchange/) (aka `7-zip`) in my scripts:

```
$szPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-zip\7z.exe
if (Test-Path $szPath) {
 Set-Alias sz $szPath -Scope Global
}
```

Then anytime I want to call that program and need to use variables specific to 7-zip I just call it:

```
sz l $filename
```

You should be able to do the same with `python` executable:

```
Set-Alias python '<Path to Python.exe' -Scope Global
```

I only use `Global` scope so it ensures I can get to anywhere in my process, so if you have any child scripts that may get called the alias is still usable.

Your other option would be to set the `python` executable path in your environment variables for Windows. Then you would be able to just call `python` as well.

Comment: You're missing the generally correct option, which is to run `script.py` as the command. Python's installer associates .py files with either python.exe or, for version 3.3+, with the py.exe launcher. The latter parses Unix-style shebangs to handle multiple installed versions of Python, and it also supports virtual Unix commands such as `/usr/bin/env python` to facilitate cross-platform scripting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this for python, but this example is from the response to "help alias"

```
PS> new-item -path alias:np -value c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Now, "np" will be an alias for notepad, and it can be used as a command, like any other alias.

Comment: You can just use `Set-Alias` as well.

Comment: @Joey This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you it works now!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with variables. You just need to ensure that Python is on your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If `C:\Python27` is your python directory, then :

```
$newPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine") + ";C:\Python27\"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $newPath, "Machine")
```

will add it to your `PATH` environment variable, and then you'll be able `python` everywhere you want to.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I input the correct path for my computer and it still doesn't recognize the term 'python'. How do I undo this action?